# WM_TIMER messages suppressed when clicking and holding the mouse over windows X button

Tags: c++, windows, windows-messages

I'm working on a game where the client needs to continue processing windows messages or else the game can be exploited.  In order to solve this problem during window re-size and drag events, we have a `WM_TIMER` message that fires every 50ms which will restart the main event loop.

The problem is that this technique is not working when a user clicks and holds over the X or minimize button of a windowed client.  (So they don't complete the click, they just halt the client.)

Using Spy++, the last messages I see are:

```
<00731> 00160D3C P WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN nHittest:HTCLOSE xPos:1150 yPos:178
<00732> 00160D3C P WM_MOUSEMOVE fwKeys:MK_LBUTTON xPos:1014 yPos:-23
```

Followed by nothing until I move the mouse, and no `WM_TIMER` messages until I let go the mouse button.

So the question is, while I'm in the state of having my mouse down over the window's X button is there something I could key off of to get the client moving again? Or something I could do so our "watchdog" `WM_TIMER` messages fire?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some system events such as system menu (as in your case) or window resizing stop regular window messages from being processed for a while. You need to re-think your architecture and maybe run a periodical operation in a secondary thread. There you can use WaitForSingleObject or just Sleep() instead of message-based timer.

Answer (score 3):

I can think of a couple possibilities.

1. When the button down happens on the non-client area, the system code may be running its own message loop until the button is released.  This message loop might not dispatch WM_TIMER messages.
2. I believe WM_TIMER is special in that it's a lower priority message.  WM_TIMER is only retrieved from the queue when there's nothing else to retrieve (sort of similar to WM_PAINT).  Windows timers eventually fire, and never sooner than the specified period, but they're not very reliable if you need a regular heartbeat.

As another person suggested, you might need to rely on a second thread to keep things alive.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using periodical [waitable timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687012%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It will run independently, in a separate thread.